# Ubuntu randomly freezes [20.04]

Tags: 20.04, xorg

While using my computer normally, X will randomly freeze: No screen updates are performed and no input works but audio still plays normally if it was playing when the freeze occurred. It happens incredibly often and the only solution I've found is SysRQ-rebooting or physically pressing the power button to shut down. I'm running 20.04.3 with everything fully updated (apt upgrade does nothing).

System Stats:

- Graphics: NVidia GTX 1650
- Processor: Intel i7-10750H
- RAM: 32 GB

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA driver: nouveau v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: nouveau 
  resolution: 1920x1080~120Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: NV167 v: 4.3 Mesa 21.0.3
```

Comment: What graphics drivers are you using?

Comment: open a terminal and issue `inxi -G`. copy the output from that command and paste it into your question - you can use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1362420/edit) link below it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you'd using the default nouveau graphics driver I'd suggest switching to the proprietary nvidia driver, which on u20 you can even do using the "additional drivers" gui element.

Comment: I installed the latest NVidia drivers (version 470) -- thank you! I will accept this answer as soon as I am able to verify the freezing has stopped

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and installing/upgrading Nvidia drivers to version 470 did not work for me but I solved my problem by upgrading the kernel ( from 5.4.0.90 to 5.4.5 )